# How to call a function of a smart contract if I only know the address of that contract in hardhat script?

Tags: remix, ethereumjs, hardhat

I have a factory contract which creates a child contract upon calling a `createChild`

function and emit an event that has the newly created child contract address. Now how to call any function of the child contract from it's address in hardhat script? I mean what's the syntax as we cannot use the Interface in the script.js or test.js files.

```
  const transaction =await collectionFactory.createChild("Dog collection","DCOl","metadata",{value:10});
  const result = await transaction.wait();

  const collectionAddress =result.events[1].args.contractAddress;
  
  const result2 =await collectionAddress.mint("I am a blue dog",20);
```

Error:

```
TypeError: collectionAddress.mint is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the contract's ABI, then using ethers.js you create a factory for that contract -

```
  const DogCollection = await ethers.getContractFactory(abi);
  const collection = await DogCollection.attach(collectionAddress);
  await collection.mint("I am a blue dog", 20)
```